# Drag image acording to mouse move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to drag an image according to mouse movement. The problem is whenever the drag starts, the image's top and left positions suddenly change with the mouse position.

When it starts it should not suddenly move to the mouse position. I want it to feel like normal dragging, but the position is changing whenever I start moving the mouse.

```
var mousedown = false;
var p;
var x=0,y=0;
var flag1 = 0;

$("#blue3").mousedown(function(){
    if(mousedown) {
        mousedown = false;
        console.log("mouse down is true");
    } else {
        mousedown = true;
        console.log("mouse down is true");
    }

});  

$("#blue3").mouseup(function(){
    if(mousedown) {
        mousedown = true;
        console.log("mouse down is false");
    } else {
        flag1 = 1;
        x = p.left;
        y = p.top;
        mousedown = false;
        console.log("mouse down is false");
    }

}); 

$("#blue3").mousemove(function(event) {
    p = $("#blue3").position();

    if(mousedown) {   
        console.log("mouse left" + event.pageX);
        console.log("image left" + p.left);
        console.log("mouse top" + event.pageY);
        console.log("ima top" + p.top);

        $("#blue3").css({"left" : event.pageX, "top" : event.pageY });
        $("#blue").css({"left" : event.pageX, "top" : event.pageY});    
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you include html and css  please

Comment: In your `mouseup` function you check `if(mousedown) {...}` and then set `mousedown = true` even though you log `"mouse down is false"`. Is that intentional?

Comment: yes..tell me something that when mouse move starts it will take image's position + or minus with mouse's position that it will not again select  older position of image and stART dragging from there . it does not make any sense.